# Can I charge a Dell XPS 9720 laptop with a USB-C phone charger?

Tags: laptop, charging, charger

On holiday with my Dell XPS 9720 and don't have my USB-C Dell charger with me. I've tried a couple of phone chargers, 10W and 15W and even after hours neither have imparted any charge.

Is there a minimum wattage needed? I assumed anything would work, albeit slowly.

Comment: Phone chargers are simply not able to put out enough power to charge a laptop. They generally do not put out high enough a voltage at high enough a current.

Comment: If you are using the laptop it will definitely not work, because you use more power than the charger supplies. A 30 Watt charger should have some effect.

Comment: I realise that @gnasher729, I did power the laptop down first 

Comment: According to this official [Dell XPS 9720 spec sheet](https://www.delltechnologies.com/asset/en-us/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/technical-support/xps-17-9720-spec-sheet.pdf.external) the AC adapter needs to be a 90W or 130W AC adapter, (USB Type-CTM). No phone adapters will output enough wattage to come close to that. Official Apple OEM USB-C chargers that come with modern iPhones only go up to 18 to 20W.

Comment: I'm writing this comment from a 65W laptop being charged with a 9V phone charger. I'm at 58% right now with an ETA of 3 hours. It works... slowly.